# More columns than column names error in a text file

Tags: r

I am trying to read a text file in R studio but getting the error. Can anyone please help me to find out what is wrong with my coding?

Text file:

```
SampleID    Temperature Genotype    GxT                                         
#q2:types   Categorical Categorical Categorical                                         
CSkab18C1   18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C2   18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C3   18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C4   18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C5   18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C6   18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C7   18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C8   18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C9   18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C10  18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C11  18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C12  18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C13  18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C14  18  III-M   III-M18                                          
CSkab18C15  18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C16  18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C17  18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C18  18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C19  18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C20  18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C21  18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C22  18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C23  18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C24  18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C25  18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab18C26  18  III-M   III-M18                                         
CSkab29C1   29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C2   29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C3   29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C4   29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C5   29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C6   29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C7   29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C8   29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C9   29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C10  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C11  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C12  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C13  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C14  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C15  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C16  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C17  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C18  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C19  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C20  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C21  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C22  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C23  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C24  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C25  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
CSkab29C26  29  III-M   III-M29                                         
IsoCS18C1   18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C2   18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C3   18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C4   18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C5   18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C6   18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C7   18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C8   18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C9   18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C10  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C11  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C12  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C13  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C14  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C15  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C16  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C17  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C18  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C19  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C20  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C21  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C22  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C23  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C24  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C25  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS18C26  18  Y-M Y-M18                                           
IsoCS29C1   29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C2   29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C3   29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C4   29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C5   29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C6   29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C7   29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C8   29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C9   29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C10  29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C11  29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C12  29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C13  29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C14  29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C15  29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C16  29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C17  29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C18  29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C19  29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C20  29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C21  29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C22  29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C23  29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C24  29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C25  29  Y-M Y-M29                                           
IsoCS29C26  29  Y-M Y-M29
```

Error:

```
metadata_genevstemp <-read_q2metadata("sample_metadata_genevstemp.txt")
Error in read.table(file, header = F, col.names = coltitles, skip = 2,  : 
  more columns than column names
```

Codes:

```
install.packages(qiime2R)
library (qiime2R)
metadata_genevstemp <-read_q2metadata("sample_metadata_genevstemp.txt")
```

I just wanted to read the file first for my further analysis but it is giving the error. But I didnt find any more columns than column names error in my text files.
Thank you

Comment: I don't know that package, but it looks to me like you might have tabs as separators the first part of the file and spaces in the second.

Comment: Can you please help me in my coding? How should I correct it?

Comment: I don't know where you are getting the data. But open the text file in a text editor that will show your white spaces.  In RStudio to do this: 
Tools -> Global Options -> Code -> Display, check "Show whitespace characters"
and see.  Also in your sample code try putting tabs starting at this line:
 IsoCS18C1   18  Y-M Y-M18

Comment: I looked up the documentation `?read_q2metadata ` and it seems to be expecting a tab separated file.  So make sure that is what you have. Also better/cleaner to read from a file.  
metadata<-read_q2metadata("q2metadata.tsv")